# Javascript function overriding prev function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a site that will have a lot of SQL on it and rater then to display it as plain text I would rater have it look like it was on SSMS I would like it automatically do this in a div statement and I do not want to have to make a div or a span for every color change I think that would be allot of extra work.
 So I want to Do it only using HTML,CSS and java script . 
**This is what i have done so far this is a work in progress**

when the first function is executed i would like the line to be all green as if i was  commenting something out and it does.
but when the second function is executes it over rides the span and changes some key words to Blue. is there a way of preventing this from happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/Fiore3636/9cfcqvLj/5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>


 <style type='text/css'>
               .greenSql{
    color: #009900 !important;
}
.SQL {
    color: #0099CC;
}
    .BlueSql {
    color: #0000FF ;
}


</style>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      function SetCodeText() {
          var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("SQL")
          var i;
               greenText(myList)
               BlueText(myList)

      };


      function BlueText(myList) {
        var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("SQL")
          for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

              alert(myList[i].innerHTML)
               var BlueSql = ["Add ","Precision ","Exit ","Primary ","Alter ","External ","Print ","Fetch ","Proc ","File ","Procedure ","As ","Fillfactor ","Public ",
"Asc ","For ","Raiserror ","Authorization ","Read ","Backup ","Freetext ","Readtext ","Begin ","Freetexttable ","Rreonfigure ","From ","References ","Break ","Full ",
"Replication ","Browse ","Function ","Restore ","Bulk ","Goto ","Restrict ","By ","Grant ","Return ","Cascade ","Group ","Revert ","Case ","Having ","Revoke ","Check ","Holdlock ",
"Checkpoint ","Idenity ","Rollback ","Close ","Identity_insert ","Rowcount ","Clustered ","Identitycol ","Rrowuidcol "," If ","Rule ","Save ","Coulmn ","Index ","Schema ",
"CommtT ","Securityaudit ","Compute ","Insert ","Select ","Consoraint ","Intersect ","Into ","Set ","Containstable ","Setuser ","Continue ","Shutdown ","Key ","Create ",
"Kill ","Statistics ","Current ","Table ","Current_date ","Lineno ","Tablesample ","Load ","Textsize ","Merge ","Then ","To ","Cursor ","Nocheck ",
"Top ","Database ","Nonclustered ","Tran ","Dbcc ","Transaction ","Deallocate ","Trigger ","Declare ","Truncate ","Default ","Of ","Delete ","Off ","Union ","Deny ","Offsets ",
"Unique ","Desc ","On ","Disk ","Open ","Distinct ","Opendatasource ","Updatetext ","Distributed ","Openquery ","Use ","Double ","Openrowset ","User ","Drop ","Openxml ",
"Values ","Dump ","Option ","Varying ","Else ","View ","End ","Order ","Waitfor ","Errlvl ","When ","Escape ","Over ","Where ","Except ","Percent ","While ","Exec ","With ","Execute ","Plan ","Writetext ","Full"
];
for (txt of BlueSql)
{

              myList[i].innerHTML = myList[i].innerHTML.split(txt).join('<span class="BlueSql">' + txt + '</span>');
              myList[i].innerHTML = myList[i].innerHTML.split(txt.toLowerCase()).join('<span class="BlueSql">' + txt.toLowerCase() + '</span>');
              myList[i].innerHTML = myList[i].innerHTML.split(txt.toUpperCase()).join('<span class="BlueSql">' + txt.toUpperCase() + '</span>');
          }
}

}


function greenText(myList) {
        var greenSql = ["--"];
          for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

for (txt of greenSql)
{
    myList[i].innerHTML = myList[i].innerHTML.split(txt).join('<span class="greenSql">' + txt);
}

}

}


</script>


</head>
<body onload="SetCodeText()">



<div class="SQL"> 
  SELECT column_name(s)<br /> Add 
FROM table_name<br />
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;<br />
Collate 
<br />
SELECT column_name(s)<br />
FROM table1<br />
RIGHT JOIN table2<br />
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;<br />

--select from  'saleslog' where  'Status' =  'saleslog' 
 <br />
 </div>


<p class="SQL"> 
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
Collate 
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name
select from  'saleslog' where  'Status' = 
 'saleslog' 
 select from  'saleslog' where  'Status' = 
 'saleslog'
 select [column_name]
FROM table_name

#include 
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
</p>


SELECT column_name(s)FROM table_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2; 
Collate SELECT column_name FROM table1 RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = 
table2.column_name select from  'saleslog' where  'Status' =  'saleslog' 








</body></html>
```

Comment: Why do it yourself, when tons of libraries already do this? You just wanted to do it as an exercise? https://highlightjs.org/?snippet=5&style=7

Comment: Yes i know about Hightlightjs.org i just wanted to try it myself

Comment: so why did you do the neg rep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way :D

```
.greenSql,  .greenSql *{
    color: #009900 !important;
}
```